# pyinstaller add-binary prepends arg with current directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Win 10, Pyinstaller 3.6, python 3.9.7 (conda)

With the command line

```
C:\Users\David\Code\Python\Unitization>pyinstaller --add-binary 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.1.dll;.' unitTracker.py
```

I get this error

```
Unable to find "C:\Users\David\Code\Python\Unitization\'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.1.dll" when adding binary and data files.
```

The problem is that pyinstaller is prepending the path I've given with the current working directory. How do I correctly specify the file to be added?

Comment: try `pyinstaller --add-binary C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.1.dll;. unitTracker.py`

Answer (score 0):

In spite of the fact that the manual shows single quotes, that's the one thing that doesn't work. No quotes, as suggested by @Alexander above works. Double quotes also work.